# Is it better to use "min-height" always in place of height in css?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Should we always try to not to give "`height`" to elements in XHTML through CSS?

if yes the i think `min-height` would be better idea instead of fixed height.

What cross browser, W3C valid css, non-javascript "min-height" method in css for browser which do not support min-height?

if i add `min-height` to any tag example `<div>` then in future in more content comes in  then will we have to change height of `div` or if `min-height` is defined then no need.

Should i use `min-height` always in place of `height`?

Answer (score 1):

> What cross browser, W3C valid css, non-javascript "min-height" method in css for browser which do not support min-height?

My workaround usually is to insert an element that does not disturb the rest of the content, and is `min-height` pixels high.

> Should i use min-height always in place of height?

There are instances when you want a height to be fixed, for example with a container whose contents are to `overflow: auto`, so I would say no, definitely not.

Answer (score 1):

No. There are plenty of times when it is sensible to use `height`. (Those times aren't when there is variable height content (including any kind of text) in elements without `overflow` set to non-default, but they exist).

> What cross browser, W3C valid css, non-javascript "min-height" method in css for browser which do not support min-height?

The only browser that people really care about which falls into that group is IE6, and it has a bug in which it treats `height` and `min-height` for `overflow: visible` content anyway. So:

```
#foo { 
  height: 10em;
  min-height: 10em;
}

html>body #foo {
  height: auto;
}
```

… or use conditional comments.